# Our favicon is ugly and asymmetric. Let's fix it!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, site-design

The favicon for this site [image] has ugly and asymmetric corners:

[image: magnified]

Compared to the corresponding icons for other beta SE sites, which only have one pixel cut off from each corner, I find the upper corners of our icon especially ugly, since the top edge of the icon shows a visible step.

I first thought it was just a glitch caused by cramming our three-letter abbreviation into an icon template that's too small for it, but on a closer look. it actually seems like there's been at least an attempt to make it fit.  Still, I think we could do better.

Jin's been known to [tweak site favicons based on community feedback before](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/cryptographys-favicon-is-inconsistent-with-larger-icons), so I figured I'd try the same here.

I've posted two suggestions for tweaked icons below; feel free to vote on them to show your preference, or post a third option if you have one.

Ps. Note that even beta site favicons apparently don't *have* to be pure text; see e.g. the favicons for [anime.SE [image: icon]](//anime.stackexchange.com), [chess.SE [image: icon]](//chess.stackexchange.com) and [poker.SE [image: icon]](//poker.stackexchange.com).  Dunno what icon would symbolize our site well, though...

<sup>(OK, so technically those icons *are* all text, or at least [valid](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/?glyph=753B) [Unicode](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/?glyph=265C) [characters](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/?glyph=2663).  Anyway, you know what I mean...)</sup>

Comment: BTW, the same corner issue also affects a bunch of other beta SE sites with "extra-wide" favicons, including [cogsci.SE], [linguistics.SE] and [dsp.SE].

Comment: Nah! your icon proposal are all for betas. I hope that we will graduate soon, so proposing a definitive icon would be better.

Comment: @Victor: I hope for that too, but let's just say [I'm not holding my breath for it.](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-long-can-a-site-like-crypto-se-be-in-beta) That said, if you have ideas for a "non-beta" logo, please do post them (either here or in a new meta thread). While I can't speak for Jin or anyone else at SE, I'd _think_ that this (when the site is fairly established, but well before graduation) would be the perfect time to make such suggestions.

Comment: I had never even noticed this. Now, I can't unsee it.

Comment: For the longest time (keep in mind I discovered this site yesterday so "longest time" < 24 hours) I thought it was "POG".

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/432/194)

Answer (score 52):

For a third option, it turns out there *is* a Unicode character for [Flag In Hole (U+26F3)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26f3/index.htm).  Here's my attempt to render it in pixel art on the standard beta SE favicon template:

[image: favicon]

[image: magnified x 8]

And a variant with a ball next to the green:

[image: favicon]

[image: magnified x 8]

I think this actually turned out pretty nice.  I'm slightly worried about is the potential for future confusion if there's ever an SE site for *real* golf, but that seems to be [covered by sports.SE](//sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golf) already, so we should be (fairly) safe.

**Edit:** Since this icon turned out so popular, I tried to make some larger versions of it for use in places like the [SE site list](http://stackexchange.com/sites) that need them.  I've posted two somewhat different large versions below ([#1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/836), [#2](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/837)); please let me know what you think of them.

Comment: I like the one with the ball, but maybe three pixels off each corner?

Comment: @hildred I personally prefer the one-pixel-off-each-corner version, just looking at the OP's other entries. *(I'm posting this as a user, not a moderator.)*

Comment: New icon? This site is evolving.. ⛳

Comment: I like the second one (ball-next-to-hole) best.

Comment: Get the same point across with one character instead of three -- I think it's very code-golf appropriate.  But I think it does lose some recognizability when blown up in pixelated form, so I'm voting for the smooth SVG version.

Comment: I'm just wondering what's going to happen if there's ever a SE site created for actual golf :D

Answer (score 28):

Since the [flag in hole icon](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/793) has turned out to be so popular, I thought I should try to draw a larger version of it to replace the [larger site icon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/img/apple-touch-icon.png) used in various places like the [SE site list](http://stackexchange.com/sites).  I ended up with two versions, so I figured I'd post both here and let you folks vote on them, just like with the smaller favicons.

Here's the first one, loosely based on the reference glyph of the Unicode [Flag In Hole character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26f3/index.htm) which the pixel art version (shown on the right for reference) was also based on:

[image: Large icon for codegolf.SE (144 x 144 px)]
[image: Medium icon for codegolf.SE (48 x 48 px)]  
[image: Pixel art favicon, shown for reference]

This one doesn't have a ball next to the green, but it wouldn't be hard to add one, if people like it.  I also have an SVG vector version of this image, but I need to clean it up before posting it here, since I did it in Inkscape rather than by hand-coding.

Comment: This feels too smooth; I feel that the hole should be a bit bigger (proportional to the small one) and that the flag should be less angled / come out lower on the pole. Maybe the pole could be a bit smaller

Comment: I like the smoothness.

Answer (score 17):

I golfed it down to 2 letters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I get why you did the wa--OHHHH it's a puzzle piece!

Answer (score 13):

How about a design based on the [Hacker emblem](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Glider.svg)? It seems to me that of all the SE sites, this one is most closely related to the [hacker subculture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_%28programmer_subculture%29).

Favicon: [image: Favicon]

[Logo:](http://jsfiddle.net/PZ9Ac/) [image: Logo]

Comment: A glider in conway's game of life is the Hacker emblem? Wow...

Comment: @Justin It takes lots of skillz to program all of your exploits in Conway's Game of Life.

Answer (score 9):

Since the [flag in hole icon](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/793) has turned out to be so popular, I thought I should try to draw a larger version of it to replace the [larger site icon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/img/apple-touch-icon.png) used in various places like the [SE site list](http://stackexchange.com/sites).  I ended up with two versions, so I figured I'd post both here and let you folks vote on them, just like with the smaller favicons.

Here's the second one, directly based on the pixel art version (shown on the right for comparison):

[image: Large icon for codegolf.SE (144 x 144 px)]
[image: Medium icon for codegolf.SE (48 x 48 px)]  
[image: Pixel art favicon, shown for reference]

This one *does* have a ball next to the green, but removing it would be trivial.  I like the rendering at full size, but I'm not perfectly happy with the way it scaled down to 48 × 48 px (middle image); some hand-tweaking might improve the results.  Still, I feel the combination of pixel art and the flag symbol does work pretty well to symbolize "code golf".

Also, for completeness, here's the original SVG code from which these were rendered.  Alas, it's a bit verbose, since SVG doesn't really do loops::

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="144" height="144"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
  <!-- meta.SE speech bubble -->
  <g fill="#62b0df" stroke="none">
    <path d="m 80,110 0,25 25,-25 z" />
    <rect width="92" height="90" rx="12" ry="15" x="26" y="25" />
  </g>
  <!-- pixel art logo -->
  <defs>
    <rect id="pixel" width="6" height="6" rx="1" ry="1" x="68" y="42"
          fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="0" y="0" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="0" y="+7" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="+7" y="+7" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="+14" y="+7" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="0" y="+14" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="0" y="+21" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="0" y="+28" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="-14" y="+35" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="0" y="+35" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="+14" y="+35" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="-21" y="+42" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="-14" y="+42" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="+14" y="+42" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="+21" y="+42" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="-14" y="+49" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="-7" y="+49" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="0" y="+49" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="+7" y="+49" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="+14" y="+49" />
  <use xlink:href="#pixel" x="+35" y="+49" />
</svg>
```

(Yes, I could've golfed it down quite a bit, but I didn't want to do that at the expense of readability.)

Comment: I think the full-scale version shouldn't be pixellated.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my first suggestion for a new favicon:

[image: new favicon]

[image: magnified x 8]

It looks the same as the other SE beta favicons, except for being two pixels wider.  This is the version I personally prefer.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Favicon]

I don't know, I like this one.

Comment: Solves the "What if there is a future Stack Exchange site devoted to *real* golf?" problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative suggestion, based on the current favicon, but with the top corners changed to match the bottom ones:

[image: new favicon]

[image: magnified x 8]

Answer (score 4):

On the recommendation in a comment I tried out Piet. Here is my first go at it.  It definitely needs some refining (eg use math to calculate the first number and see if we can get the program to feed into the bottom of the flag), but I wondered if this kind of thing would work. It outputs `Golf`

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it's a bit too esoteric.

Comment: Looks very phallic... :/

Answer (score 3):

My tries:

- [image: clean PCG] [image: clean PCG big] – original “P”, cleaner “C”, [Joe Z.'s](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/822) “G”
- [image: PPCG] [image: PPCG big] – there is enough space for the complete abbreviation: “PPCG”
- [image: large PCG] [image: large PCG big] – or just use larger characters
- [image: PCG shadow] [image: PCG shadow big] – maybe with shadow, black as the new top bar

Comment: If you're resizing those images in GIMP, try to use "no interpolation" rather than cubic or sinc.

Comment: I resized none. The big images are actually the small versions produced automatically by imgur.com.

Comment: Oh. In that case, would you mind providing manually resized versions? Those ones are too blurry.

Comment: GIMP is great, but I'm a command-line guy. `convert -filter point -resize 128` ;)

Comment: Anyway, I like the first one.

Answer (score 3):

I like the golf flag idea very much. With a few more pixels tweaked, it would be possible to also suggest puzzle pieces, two Ps, one reflected, (programming puzzles), to accompany the golf flag.

[image: icon for codegolf]

Answer (score -2):

Since this site is about challenges, code, obfuscation, and of course golfing, how about this?

[image]

and larger

[image]

It is a whitespace program where the three characters have been converted to red, green, and blue. I'll leave it to you figure out what it's output is.

Comment: The last time this topic came up (which I'd forgotten about until this answer reminded me), there was a [proposal to use a Piet program](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/451/194).

Answer (score -3):

I personally think the font could use some tweaking, like this:

[image: slightly different PCG font]

[image: slightly different PCG font x8]

or this:

[image: slightly different PCG font #2]

[image: slightly different PCG font #2 x8]

Mostly I feel like the top-right corner of the G looks like it's jutting out top-heavily in the current logo.

Comment: Sorry, I tend to read this one “DOG”. Would prefer the original “P” instead.

Answer (score -4):

How about an icon that looks like a golf ball heading toward a hole, but the golf ball is a `0` and the flag is a `1`? Or would this be too subtle/too difficult to work out?