# Would PPCG user interface design contests be out of place?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

We are still in beta and, as far as I know, stuck with the standard beta user interface of stack exchange sites. But clearly other stack exchanges have custom layouts and graphics for their logo, favicon, buttons, etc.:

[image: ee se]

In my quick search I've found [very little definitive information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64169/themes-on-stackexchange) on how these graphics are chosen and who designs them.

My main questions are:

1. Can we the users help design the interface for PPGC for the eventual day when it graduates from beta? (If it ever does.)
2. Would programming puzzles that involved the creation of these graphics/layouts be out of place on PPGC?

I'm sure some more experienced users can chime in for the first question.

As for the second, I know that, say, a popularity contest for designing upvote and downvote button graphics might be more of an art contest, whose validity is not always certain and [has been discussed before](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/the-line-between-art-and-programming).
However I believe that such a contest, properly formulated, would be quite interesting to many users, ***especially*** if it was known that the winner's graphics would really be used once the site goes out of beta. (Exactly what constitutes such a "properly formulated" question is another topic.)

It seems very fitting that obfuscated chunks of code would be used to generate most of the graphics on one of the foremost programming puzzle websites.

(If you think "art contests" are out of the questions, what about having "logo contests" on meta. We already had one for favicons: [Our favicon is ugly and asymmetric. Let's fix it!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/788/our-favicon-is-ugly-and-asymmetric-lets-fix-it/822#822), though I don't know if it did or even could get anywhere.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sites only get custom designs, UI elements, etc. after graduation. The community typically has very little influence on this, and it is done by a professional designer at Stack Exchange.

However, once the design is complete, users are asked to give feedback and suggest improvements. For an example of this process, see [Academia.SE's site design meta post.](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/891/14308)

Comment: Although we wouldn't have a say in whether they get used, would showing strong community support for a given logo/design element have a chance of influencing the choices made by the professional designers? That is, will they see our question and its answers?

Comment: @githubphagocyte I'm fairly certain we do get some input. It happened with Physics.SE (see [first design](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/447/design-for-physics-se) and [final design](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/new-site-design)).

Comment: @KyleKanos that's good to know. I see no reason not to have competition questions then - whether on meta or main I don't mind.

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, that happens *after* the initial prototype. (See my second paragraph.)